# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BaseClient.read_output' was never awaited

Tags: python, async-await, discord

For some reason when I'm trying to use PyPresence to set a Discord rich presence that is the same as my Xbox Live presence but I keep getting an error saying `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BaseClient.read_output' was never awaited`.

This is my code

```
import os
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from xbox.webapi.api.client import XboxLiveClient
from xbox.webapi.authentication.manager import AuthenticationManager
from xbox.webapi.authentication.models import OAuth2TokenResponse

from pypresence import Presence
import requests
import time

clientID = os.environ.get("CLIENT_ID")
clientSecret = os.environ.get("CLIENT_SECRET")

discordAppID = os.environ.get("DISCORD_APP_ID")
rpc = Presence(discordAppID)
rpc.connect()

async def async_main():
    tokens_file = "./tokens.json"
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        authManager = AuthenticationManager(session, clientID, clientSecret, "")
        with open(tokens_file, mode = "r") as f:
              token = f.read()
        authManager.oauth = OAuth2TokenResponse.parse_raw(token)

        xblClient = XboxLiveClient(authManager)

        rpc.update(state = "test state")

asyncio.run(async_main())
```

The error doesn't happen when I take out the line `rpc.update(state="test state")` so I know that it's the reason for the error but I can't figure out why it is resulting in an error and how I can fix it.

Edit: It's also saying `RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I was able to fix the error by installing a package called nest_asyncio and then adding the following at the start of my code:

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```